# What is the replacement Sql Char(13) and isnull in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am new to Entity framework, Can any body tell me how to write the following query into Entity framework.

```
select column1 + char(13) +isnull(column2,space(1))+char(13)+isnull(column3,space(1))+char(13)+isnull(column4,space(1)) +char(13)+isnull(olumn5,space(1)) as FADRS
FROM table
```

Convert the above query into Entity Framework.

By using Jon answer i get the answer. Know my problem is how to use iqueryable

```
            IQuer<string> Madr = from b in context.table
                       where b.column1 == txtaddrss.Text
                       select new
                   {FADR = b.column2 + '\r' +
                   (b.column3 ?? " ") + '\r' +
                   (b.column4 ?? " ") + '\r' +
                    (b.column5 ?? " ") + '\r' +
                    (b.column6 ?? " ")};

            foreach(string something in Madr)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(something);
              }
```

i am getting error conversion failed because of anonymous type

Comment: Basically you wouldn't. You can do raw sql but then your design becomes fragile. A view or a stored procedure maybe, but I'd just do it client side I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char(13)` just does the equivalent (though more limited) of `(char)13` in C#, which would just return `'\r'`.

Hence you would either use `'\r'` or `"\r"`.

`isnull(x, y)`just does the equivalent of `x ?? y` in C#.

So you would use something like:

```
var query = from item in TableSource select
  item.column1 + '\r' +
  (item.column2 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column3 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column4 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column5 ?? " ");
```

`TableSource` is whatever way you are getting a reference to the table (`context.Table` or whatever).

`query` will be an `IQueryable<string>` returning the relevant strings when invoked. If you really want the `FADRS` name from your example then the following will instead of strings return anonymous objects with a `FADRS` property:

```
var query = from item in TableSource select
  new {FADRS = item.column1 + '\r' +
  (item.column2 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column3 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column4 ?? " ") + '\r' +
  (item.column5 ?? " ")};
```

Edit:

The first example above can be used as:

```
foreach(string something in query)
  MessageBox.Show(something);
```

The second example as:

```
foreach(var something in query)
  MessageBox.Show(something.FADR);
```

With the first `var` is optional shorthand, with the second you must use `var` as the types involved are anonymous, and hence `var` is the only way to name the type (by not naming it at all).

Comment: can you explain how to use Iqueryable. i am trying but i am not getting

Comment: Like `IEnumerable`: `foreach(var x in query){dosomething(x);}`. Unlike `IEnumerable`, if you apply further LINQ methods like `Select()`, `Where()` etc. then rather than being performed in-memory, it alters the query that is eventually turned into SQL. E.g. with the first example above if you did `foreach(string s in query.Where(s.Length > 20))Console.WriteLine(s);` then the SQL be the same as yours but with `WHERE len(column1 + char(13) +isnull(column2,space(1))+char(13)+isnull(column3,space(1))+char(13)+isnull(column4,space(1)) +char(13)+isnull(column5,space(1))) > 20` added

Comment: ... generally, you don't want to move to an `IEnumerable`-only use, until you need to do something only-possible in-memory (there are exceptions, but it's a good guideline), because the fact that `IQueryable` gets converted into just the necessary SQL makes Linq-based approaches to object-relational conversion approach that of hand-coded SQL in many cases.

Comment: Done so. The main thing was that you were mixing parts of my first example (which produces an `IQueryable<string>`) and the second (which produces an `IQueryable<T>` where the `T` is an anonymous type, and hence can't be named, making the use of `var` compulsory).

Answer (score 0):

Given no further context I'd say sonething like this:

```
var query = from obj in context.table
        select  new  { 
            FADR = obj.column1 + "\r" + 
        obj.column2 ?? " " + "\r" + 
        obj.column3 ?? " " + "\r" +
        obj.column4 ?? " " + "\r" +
        obj.column5 ?? " " + "\r" };
```